# Connection reset on AXFR queries

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, dns-zone

I'm trying to setup maradns and maradns-zoneserver to allow AXFR queries. Maradns is doing as master server. I want to allow external secondary dns servers to transfer my zone. Unfortunately

```
dig @XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX +tcp axfr mydomain.com
```

Results with

```
;; communications error to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX#53: connection reset
```

I have checked if port 53 is listening (and it is):

```
marverix@myvps:~$ netstat -tulnp | grep 53
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:53        0.0.0.0:*                           -
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I haven't configured [long_packet_ipv4](http://maradns.samiam.org/tutorial/dnstcp.html).